# Restrict Azure DevOps access from Azure virtual desktop

Tags: azure, devops, vdi

We have a requirement to restrict Azure DevOps service only from our Azure Virtual Desktop environment.

We have deployed Azure AD Premium P2 with conditional access restricting to internal IP Range but problem is while using Azure Virtual Desktop the outgoing public ip is dynamic. We don't want to use NAT Gateway.

Is there any alternative using conditional access policy to restrict DevOps?
Please help.

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK conditional access is your only option to restrict access to DevOps. The best solution would be to use Azure Firewall or NAT gateway to give your AVD hosts a static outbound IP address. The only alternative would be to give each AVD host a public IP and use NSGs to restrict inbound access, but this is not a great design.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best solution but you can narrow the list of IPs by the region using this, dynamically updated, list of IPs: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519.

e.g. for WEU it is:

```
{
  "name": "WindowsVirtualDesktop.WestEurope",
  "id": "WindowsVirtualDesktop.WestEurope",
  "properties": {
    "changeNumber": 2,
    "region": "westeurope",
    "regionId": 18,
    "platform": "Azure",
    "systemService": "WindowsVirtualDesktop",
    "addressPrefixes": [
      "13.69.82.138/32",
      "40.68.18.120/32",
      "40.114.241.90/32",
      "51.136.28.200/32",
      "51.137.89.79/32",
      "52.137.2.50/32",
      "65.52.158.177/32",
      "104.40.156.194/32",
      "104.214.237.23/32",
      "137.117.171.26/32",
      "168.63.31.54/32"
    ],
    "networkFeatures": null
  }
}
```

However agree with a @jamiecon, NAT Gw and you good to go.